# Javascript - Posting Images to Twitter with No Duplicates

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, twitter, bots

I'm making a Twitter bot with a NPM package called Twit and was wondering how I would post images to Twitter without posting duplicate images.

Currently the image_path variable

```
var image_path = path.join(__dirname, '/images/' + random_from_array(images))
```

is looking through my image directory, but I don't want it to upload duplicate images.  I've tried multiple things, but am stuck.  Any suggestions, I'm stumped.

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    path = require('path'),
    Twit = require('twit'),
    config = require(path.join(__dirname, 'config.js'));

var T = new Twit(config);

function random_from_array(images){
  return images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)];
} 

function upload_random_image(images){
  console.log('Opening an image...');
  var image_path = path.join(__dirname, '/images/' + random_from_array(images)),
      b64content = fs.readFileSync(image_path, { encoding: 'base64' });

  console.log('Uploading an image...');

  T.post('media/upload', { media_data: b64content }, function (err, data, response) {
    if (err){
      console.log('ERROR:');
      console.log(err);
    }
    else{
      console.log('Image uploaded!');
      console.log('Now tweeting it...');

      T.post('statuses/update', {
        media_ids: new Array(data.media_id_string)
      },
        function(err, data, response) {
          if (err){
            console.log('ERROR:');
            console.log(err);
          }
          else{
            console.log('Posted an image!');
          }
        }
      );
    }
  });
}

fs.readdir(__dirname + '/images', function(err, files) {
  if (err){
    console.log(err);
  }
  else{
    var images = [];
    files.forEach(function(f) {
      images.push(f);
    });

    setInterval(function(){
      upload_random_image(images);
    }, 10000);
  }
});
```

I'm following this tutorial

https://botwiki.org/resource/tutorial/random-image-tweet/#posting-images

Answer (score 2):

You can keep a list of all the images that have been uploaded. There are several ways you could go about doing this:

### The simplest solution

Keep the list of uploaded images as a global variable. Before uploading a new image, check if that image is in the list. If it is, return early. If it's not, put the image into the list and continue.

```js
const uploadedImages = []
function upload_random_image(images){
  console.log('Opening an image...');
  const image = random_from_array(images)
  // check if image is in the list
  if (uploadedImages.includes(image) {
     return;
  }
  // image is not in the list - insert into the list and continue
  uploadedImages.push(image);
  const image_path = path.join(__dirname, '/images/', image)
  // ...
```

One downside of this approach is that you will end up with "gaps" in the timing of uploading images - if the image was already uploaded, your program will have to wait until the next interval has elapsed before trying again. Also, we don't have a way to know when all the images from the folder have been uploaded.

#### A more optimal approach

A better approach (in my opinion) would be to randomize the images first, and pass them one at a time to the `upload_random_image` function, which would now become just an `upload_image` function. We would need a `shuffle` function for that - there are many solutions to creating one online, or you could use a utility library like [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#shuffle). Assuming a `shuffle` function exists:

```js
    // ...
    var images = [];
    files.forEach(function(f) {
      images.push(f);
    });
    const shuffled = shuffle(images)
    let index = 0;
    setInterval(function(){
      const image = shuffled[index]
      upload_image(image);
      index += 1; 
    }, 10000);
  }
});

function upload_image(image){
  console.log('Opening an image...');
  var image_path = path.join(__dirname, '/images/' + image)
  // ...
}
```

The remaining problem now is that we will reach the end of the `shuffled` array at some point. This really indicates that we have uploaded all the images in that folder and our job is done. To be able to stop, we need to use the return value of `setInterval`, which is the `intervalID`. We save the return value of `setInterval` into a variable, and call [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval) once we want to stop:

```js
    const shuffled = shuffle(images)
    let index = 0;
    const intervalId = setInterval(function(){
      const image = shuffled[index]
      upload_image(image);
      index += 1; 
      if (index === shuffled.length) {
        clearInterval(intervalId)
      }
    }, 10000);
```

I've posted an example using `shuffle` and `clearInterval` to this [repl](https://repl.it/@lizraeli/ShuffleClearInterval).

Comment: You're the man, I really appreciate all the help. Thank you so much!!!